# ui-router onEnter hook fired multiple times

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm migrating my app to ui-router 1.0.0 and I have this issue with nested states, when onEnter $transitions hook fires as many times, as many parents the state has (i.e. how deep it is nested), regardless of whether I filter states in my hook or not. Is this expected or a bug?

```
$stateProvider
  .state("root", {
    url: "/"
  })
  .state("root.child", {
    url: "/child"
  })
  .state("root.child.child", {
    url: "/child",
      data: {
      foo: "bar"
    }
  });


$transitions.onEnter(
  {to: state => state.data && state.data.foo === "bar"},
  transition =>
    console.log(`on enter triggered`, transition.from(),   transition.to())
);

$state.go("root.child.child");
```

In this example the hook is fired 3 times.

Here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0gLs9h7y/1/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I created an issue on github with same question, and christopherthielen, the top contributor of the ui-router gave me a comprehensive answer to this question, which I'm obliged to post here in case someone comes across the same problem.*

---

This is expected based on how you coded your hook. The `onEnter` hook is a state based. The pseudocode for processing `onEnter` is as follows:

When initially going to `root.child.child` there are three states being entered: `root`, `root.child`, `root.child.child`.

Your criteria is `{ to: state => state.data && state.data.foo === "bar" }` which *matches for each of the three states being entered*. This is because although three states are being entered, there is only one "to state", which is `root.child.child`. That state's data has the `foo: 'bar'` data, so it matches.

You should change your criteria to use `entering` instead of `to`.

```
{ entering: state => state.data && state.data.foo === 'bar' }
```

Here's an updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2m63pvqb/1/

Some other approaches that might work:

Put `onEnter` on the state itself

```
  .state("root.child.child", {
    url: "/child",
      data: {
      foo: "bar"
    },
   onEnter: ($transition$, $state$) => do something specific when entering root.child.child 
  });
```

do something ONCE per transition if any states being entered have data.foo === 'bar'

```
   $transitions.onStart({ entering: state => state.data && state.data.foo === 'bar' }, trans => 
      // do something
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the app.js for checking if the enterbutton hitted. There u can insert a function like `$rootScope.hitEnter = function(){ });` in the run-area. That should work better then in the config-area.

Comment: I don't think your answer is related to my question :(

Comment: Did you add youre code in the run-part?  There a function should only fired once...